# Downloading a file over HTTP from SSIS package not working

Tags: c#, sql, api, http, ssis

My SSIS package has a script task to download a file from a third party URL. This used to work fine until recently.

Failure occurs on execution of method HttpClientConnection.DownloadFile() with this Error

```
Error: Download failed: Exception from HRESULT: 0xC0016003
```

Here is the snippet of the code

```
Object mySSISConnection = Dts.Connections["test HTTP Connection Manager"].AcquireConnection(null);
HttpClientConnection myConnection = new HttpClientConnection(mySSISConnection);
myConnection.DownloadFile(Dts.Connections["XXXDownload File LocationXXX"].ConnectionString, true);
```

Also Note:

1. When I test this connection from Connection manager properties , it succeeds.
2. I am also able to download the file from a browser by using the same URL from the box without any issue.
3. When I change the URL in the package to download file from some other site the package executes successfully.

Let me know if you need further information.

Comment: What happens if you combine the first two lines of your code snippet into: `HttpClientConnection myConnection = new HttpClientConnection(Dts.Connections["test HTTP Connection Manager"].AcquireConnection(null));`?

Comment: Check the `XXXDownload File LocationXXX` connection as well. Does the file already exist? Does the account that runs the package have write permissions in the target folder?

Comment: @digital.aaron Still the same error when combined.

Comment: @WolfgangKais Yes the file exists, it gets overwritten when i use a different URL. So there should not be a problem at the destination.

Comment: Yes, there "should" not be a problem, unless the file is locked by another process or the execution account has insufficient permissions on the existing file. Maybe it's worth a look.